# how to set a date with string data type to calendar data type

Tags: java

My input is 
`String a1="2003-08-15";`

I want to set `a1` in a pojo class of type Calendar..

Here is my code..

```
String a1="2003-08-15";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(a1);
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.setTime(date);
item.setDate1(calender);
```

My output looks like this: `"0021-01-22 12:30:00"`

Is this correct output??

Comment: Look at your date and look at your format... there is something wrong there

Comment: Do you use Java 8 or above? If yes, it is strongly recommended not to use `java.util` for date time operations anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
String a1="2003-08-15";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(a1));
Date date=cal. getTime();
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: i got the same output

Comment: Now check the answer